# How to create real time image effect processing application iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing

I use AVCaptureSession to receive image from camera of iPhone. It return image in delegate function. In this function, I create image and call other thread to process this image:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
    //    static bool isFirstTime = true;
    //    if (isFirstTime == false) {
    //        return;
    //    }
    //    isFirstTime = false;

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    //Lock the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    //Get information about the image
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    //Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst/*kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast*/);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);

    // release some components
    CGContextRelease(newContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    UIImage* uiimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
    CGImageRelease(newImage);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImageForImageView:) withObject:uiimage waitUntilDone:YES];
    if(processImageThread == nil || (processImageThread != nil && processImageThread.isExecuting == false)){
        [processImageThread release];
        processImageThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(processImage:) object:uiimage];
        [processImageThread start];
    }

    [pool drain];
}
```

I process image on another thread, use CIFilters:

```
- (void) processImage:(UIImage*)image{
    NSLog(@"Begin process");
    CIImage* ciimage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
    CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome"];// keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, ciimage, "inputRadius", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0f], nil];
    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:ciimage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [filter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:1.0] forKey:@"inputColor"];
    CIImage* ciResult = [filter outputImage];

    CIContext* context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:ciResult fromRect:[ciResult extent]];
    UIImage* uiResult = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    CFRelease(cgImage);

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImageForImageView:) withObject:uiResult waitUntilDone:YES];
    NSLog(@"End process");
}
```

And set result image for a layer:

```
- (void) setImageForImageView:(UIImage*)image{
    self.view.layer.contents = image.CGImage;
}
```

But it is **very laggy**. I found a open source, it create a real time image effect application very smooth (also use AVCaptureSession. So, what is difference here (my code and their code) ? **How to create  real time image effect processing application ?**

This is the link of open source: https://github.com/gobackspaces/DLCImagePickerController#readme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The open source sample that you specified in your question using an outstanding open source library [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) by BradLarson for the real time photo and video processing. This library uses GPU-based filters (OpenGL ES 2.0) for image processing. Comparatively it is faster than the CPU-based image fileters that you are using by the `core image` framework.

**[GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#overview)**

> The GPUImage framework is a BSD-licensed iOS library that lets you apply GPU-accelerated filters and other effects to images, live camera video, and movies. In comparison to Core Image (part of iOS 5.0), GPUImage allows you to write your own custom filters, supports deployment to iOS 4.0, and has a simpler interface. However, it currently lacks some of the more advanced features of Core Image, such as facial detection.
>
> For massively parallel operations like processing images or live video frames, GPUs have some significant performance advantages over CPUs. On an iPhone 4, a simple image filter can be over 100 times faster to perform on the GPU than an equivalent CPU-based filter.

Comment: I also try to use OpenGL, but it is still laggy. I think cause is I have to read UIImage from camera to byte array. Can I get texture from captureOutput delegate ?

Comment: @huync - You can look at the code I use to do the video uploading in GPUImageVideoCamera and see how I approach this. Basically, I either directly upload the the bytes from within the CVPixelBufferRef or preferably use iOS 5.0's support for texture caches to do a fast upload to OpenGL ES. In the code above, you're converting your CVPixelBufferRed to a UIImage, which is a very slow process and is unnecessary for uploading the raw image bytes to Core Image. Again, you can look at my BenchmarkSuite sample application to see how you want to do this for using Core Image. GPUImage is faster, though.

Comment: @BradLarson : Thank you very much. Your project is very greate, big and useful project. I've used it before. I will look at your code.